# How to solve this equation with % operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, equation

Hello this problem is already giving me goosebumps , let's say i have this equation :

`(12*6015)%26=4`

how to make the inverse?

like we don't know the value is 12 , i only have the result that is 4 :

`(x*6015)%26=4`

that's confusing to me because i never faced this before.

Comment: In that case, there are a lot of values for `x`. The `%` is used to calculate the remainder. For example `x % 3 = 1`, `x` could be any of these values: `1`, `4`, `7`, `10`, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, find a number from 0 to 100 and return a match of the ecuation.

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Won't necessarily work for every case. Take for example `(x * 999) % 1233 = 1026`

Comment: Thanks , i figured out that the range i wanted was also 26 that is the number of letters in the alphabet , so it will work with any value.